# what is the difference between jpanel.updateUI() and jpanel.repaint() and toolkit.getDefultToolkit().sync() in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, frame-rate

I'm making a simple app and learning with practicing how FPS-related methods work in java to make an app with a high fresh rate but, I don't know which one of the methods above should I use. my app have a button and a text field and a simple layout manager that I made which is supposed to change the location of the components according to the primal frame size (using ratio). the layout manager should be able to update the panel (or my frame I don't know really) every time that a component's location changed. also while the user is changing the frame size the components should move smoothly and without being laggy. how can I accomplish all these? right now my problem is shown below which seems that the panel.updateUI() doesn't do anything.

[image]

as you see there is a black line that will appear when you change the frame size slowly, and it doesn't disappear. when you do it fast it becomes bigger and you see it clearly but it disappears, while in FPS above 60 you shouldn't be able to see such a thing.

this is how I'm doing this currently:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private SwingWorker<Void, Void> sw;
    private JTextField txtGi;
    protected volatile static boolean b = false;
    private double FPS = 0;
    protected static volatile JButton btnStart;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Test window = new Test();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 230, 230);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(230, 230));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 216, 193);
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.setName("btnStart");
        btnStart.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 17));
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(frame.getMinimumSize());

                    System.out.println(
                        "#sw.isDone(): " + sw.isDone() + " sw.isCancelled(): " + sw.isCancelled() + " b: " + b);

                }
            });
        btnStart.setBounds(50, 120, 101, 33);
        panel.add(btnStart);
        System.out.println("1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        frame.validate();
        panel.validate();
        sw = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

                b = true;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is going to sleep for 250 millis.");
                System.out.println(frame.isShowing());
                while (frame.isShowing() == false) {
                    System.out.println("initializing the frame.");
                    Thread.sleep(320);
                }

                System.out.println(frame.isShowing());
                int cc = 0;
                int FC = 0;

                while (frame.isShowing()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                    panel.updateUI();
                    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    cc++;

                    Graphical_AI.setComponentLocationWithButton(btnStart);

                    System.out.println("3: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    if (Graphical_AI.thread1.isAlive()) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("waiting for " + Graphical_AI.thread1.getName() + " to finish!");
                        System.out.println();
                        Graphical_AI.thread1.join();
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        panel.updateUI();

                    }

                    Graphical_AI.setComponentLocationWithButton(txtGi);

                    if (Graphical_AI.thread1.isAlive()) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println("waiting for " + Graphical_AI.thread1.getName() + " to finish!");
                        System.out.println();
                        Graphical_AI.thread1.join();
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                        panel.updateUI();

                    }

                    long e = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    FPS = 1.0 / ((e - s) / 1000.0);

                    FC++;
                    if (FC == 60) {
                        txtGi.setText(String.valueOf("FPS: " + (int) FPS));
                        FC = 0;
                    }

                    System.out.println("FPS: " + (int) FPS);

                    if (cc == 1000) {
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                        cc = 0;
                        System.gc();
                        System.out.println("memory optimized.");

                    }

                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<Void> chunks) {
                super.process(chunks);
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                System.out.println("sw.isDone(): " + sw.isDone() + " b: " + b);
                super.done();
            }

        };
        sw.execute();

        txtGi = new JTextField();
        txtGi.setName("txtGi");
        txtGi.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 21));
        txtGi.setBounds(50, 40, 134, 70);
        panel.add(txtGi);
        txtGi.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

the layout manager:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Graphical_AI {

    protected static volatile int count = 0;
    protected static volatile int C_X;
    protected static volatile int C_Y;
    protected static double x_C_To_E_ratio;
    protected static double y_C_To_E_ratio;
    protected static int C_WIDTH;
    protected static int C_HEIGHT;
    protected static int Con_WIDTH;
    protected static int Con_HEIGHT;
    protected static volatile int N_C_X;
    protected static volatile int N_C_Y;
    protected static Container con;
    protected volatile static boolean bool = false;
    protected static volatile ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
    protected static volatile ArrayList<String> al_for_O_names = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected static volatile String C_Name;
    protected static volatile String C_O_Name;
    protected volatile static boolean bool2 = false;
    protected static volatile Thread thread1;

    protected static void analyzeJComponentSize(JComponent comp) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("W: " + comp.getWidth() + " H: " + comp.getHeight());
        Thread.sleep(30);
    }

    protected static void analyzeJFrameSize(JFrame frame) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("W: " + frame.getWidth() + " H: " + frame.getHeight());
        Thread.sleep(30);
    }

    protected static void setComponentLocationWithButton(JComponent comp) throws InterruptedException {

        thread1 = Thread.currentThread();
        thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    System.out.println("count: " + count);
                    C_Name = comp.getName();
                    System.out.println("C_Name: " + C_Name);

                    if (count == 0) {
                        C_O_Name = comp.getName();
                        System.out.println("C_O_Name: " + C_O_Name);

                        con = comp.getParent();

                        Con_WIDTH = con.getWidth();
                        Con_HEIGHT = con.getHeight();

                        System.out.println("** (double) Con_WIDTH: " + (double) Con_WIDTH);
                        System.out.println("** (double) Con_HEIGHT: " + (double) Con_HEIGHT);

                        x_C_To_E_ratio = (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX();
                        y_C_To_E_ratio = (double) con.getHeight() / (double) comp.getY();

                        if (bool2 == false) {
                            al.add(x_C_To_E_ratio);
                            al.add(y_C_To_E_ratio);
                            al_for_O_names.add(comp.getName());
                            bool2 = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("** x_C_To_E_ratio: " + x_C_To_E_ratio);
                        System.out.println("** y_C_To_E_ratio: " + y_C_To_E_ratio);

                        System.out.println("** (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX(): "
                            + (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX());

                        C_X = comp.getX();
                        C_Y = comp.getY();
                        C_WIDTH = comp.getWidth();
                        C_HEIGHT = comp.getHeight();

                        System.out.println("** C_WIDTH: " + C_WIDTH + ", " + C_HEIGHT);

                        System.out.println("** (double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X): " + (double) con.getWidth() + " / "
                            + (double) C_X);

                        count++;
                    }

                    if (C_Name != al_for_O_names.get(0)) {
                        count = 0;
                        System.out.println("%% C_Name: " + C_Name);
                        System.out.println("%% C_O_Name: " + C_O_Name);
                        System.out.println("%% al_for_O_names.get(0): " + al_for_O_names.get(0));
                        System.out.println("%% count became to:" + count);
                        al_for_O_names.remove(0);
                        al_for_O_names.add(comp.getName());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("*ELSE STATEMENT*");
                        count = 1;
                    }

                    if (count == 0) {
                        C_Name = comp.getName();
                        System.out.println("$$ C_Name: " + C_Name);

                        con = comp.getParent();

                        Con_WIDTH = con.getWidth();
                        Con_HEIGHT = con.getHeight();

                        System.out.println("$$ (double) Con_WIDTH: " + (double) Con_WIDTH);
                        System.out.println("$$ (double) Con_HEIGHT: " + (double) Con_HEIGHT);

                        x_C_To_E_ratio = (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX();
                        y_C_To_E_ratio = (double) con.getHeight() / (double) comp.getY();

                        if (bool2 == false) {
                            al.add(x_C_To_E_ratio);
                            al.add(y_C_To_E_ratio);
                            bool2 = true;
                        }

                        System.out.println("$$ x_C_To_E_ratio: " + x_C_To_E_ratio);
                        System.out.println("$$ y_C_To_E_ratio: " + y_C_To_E_ratio);

                        System.out.println("$$ (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX(): "
                            + (double) con.getWidth() / (double) comp.getX());

                        C_X = comp.getX();
                        C_Y = comp.getY();
                        C_WIDTH = comp.getWidth();
                        C_HEIGHT = comp.getHeight();

                        System.out.println("$$ C_WIDTH: " + C_WIDTH + ", " + C_HEIGHT);

                        System.out.println("$$ (double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X): " + (double) con.getWidth() + " / "
                            + (double) C_X);

                        count++;
                    }

                    try {
                        System.out.println("## after if count block ## comp W: " + comp.getWidth() + " comp H: "
                            + comp.getHeight() + "\ncomp.getLocation(): " + comp.getLocation()
                            + " comp.getLocationOnScreen(): " + comp.getLocationOnScreen());
                        System.out.println("con W: " + con.getWidth() + ", con H: " + con.getHeight());

                        if (x_C_To_E_ratio != al.get(0) || y_C_To_E_ratio != al.get(1)) {
                            x_C_To_E_ratio = al.get(0);
                            y_C_To_E_ratio = al.get(1);
                            Thread.sleep(2);
                        }

                        if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) > x_C_To_E_ratio + 0.025) {
                            Thread.sleep(2);
                            System.out.println((((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X)) + " ,,, " + x_C_To_E_ratio);
                            while (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) > x_C_To_E_ratio + 0.025) {

                                C_X += 1;
                                N_C_X = C_X;
                                if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) < x_C_To_E_ratio + 0.025) {
                                    System.out.println("## in if bigger ## ");
                                    break;
                                }

                                System.out.println("## in if bigger ## C_X: " + C_X + ", N_C_X " + N_C_X);

                                System.out.println("## in if bigger ## (double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X: "
                                    + (double) con.getWidth() + " / " + (double) C_X);
                                System.out.println("## in if bigger ## ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X): "
                                    + ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) + ", x_C_To_E_ratio:" + x_C_To_E_ratio
                                    + ", ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio: "
                                    + (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio));

                                if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio
                                || ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) - x_C_To_E_ratio < 0.002) {
                                    bool = true;
                                    System.out.println("## in if bigger ## GI.bool: " + bool);
                                    System.out.println("## in if bigger ## W: " + comp.getWidth() + " H: "
                                        + comp.getHeight() + "\ncomp.getLocation(): " + comp.getLocation()
                                        + " comp.getLocationOnScreen(): " + comp.getLocationOnScreen() + " Con_WIDTH: "
                                        + Con_WIDTH + " Con_HEIGHT: " + Con_HEIGHT + " con.getWidth(): "
                                        + con.getWidth() + " con.getHeight(): " + con.getHeight());
                                    System.out.println("## in if bigger ## $GI.bool: " + bool + " $Test.b: " + Test.b);
                                    break;
                                }

                                comp.setBounds(N_C_X, comp.getY(), C_WIDTH, C_HEIGHT);
                            }
                        }

                        else if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) < x_C_To_E_ratio - 0.025) {

                            Thread.sleep(2);
                            System.out.println((((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X)) + " *** " + x_C_To_E_ratio);
                            while (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) < x_C_To_E_ratio - 0.025) {

                                C_X -= 1;
                                N_C_X = C_X;

                                if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) > x_C_To_E_ratio - 0.025) {
                                    break;
                                }

                                System.out.println("C_X: " + C_X + ", N_C_X " + N_C_X);

                                System.out.println("(double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X): " + (double) con.getWidth()
                                    + " / " + (double) C_X);
                                System.out.println("((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X): "
                                    + ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) + ", x_C_To_E_ratio:" + x_C_To_E_ratio
                                    + ", ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio: "
                                    + (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio));

                                if (((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) == x_C_To_E_ratio
                                || ((double) con.getWidth() / (double) C_X) - x_C_To_E_ratio > -0.002) {
                                    bool = true;
                                    System.out.println("GA.bool: " + bool);
                                    System.out.println("W: " + comp.getWidth() + " H: " + comp.getHeight()
                                        + "\ncomp.getLocation(): " + comp.getLocation()
                                        + " comp.getLocationOnScreen(): " + comp.getLocationOnScreen() + " Con_WIDTH: "
                                        + Con_WIDTH + " Con_HEIGHT: " + Con_HEIGHT + " con.getWidth(): "
                                        + con.getWidth() + " con.getHeight(): " + con.getHeight());
                                    System.out.println("$GA.bool: " + bool + " $T.b: " + Test.b);
                                    break;
                                }

                                comp.setBounds(N_C_X, comp.getY(), C_WIDTH, C_HEIGHT);

                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        thread1.start();
    }
}
```

** Now the components don't seem to be laggy when you moving them while I appreciate it if you have any better solution.

** I don't want to use the pack() method or any prebuilt layout manager.

** I've already read a lot of similar questions but I didn't find my answer.

** I'm using eclipse windowbuilder.

Comment: What version of Java are you using and what operating system are you developing with?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc OpenJDK 14 and I'm doing this on windows 10

Comment: You are using the `SwingWorker` incorrectly. You should NOT be updating the state of the panel in the `doInBackground()` method. If you want to update the GUI you need to "publish" the results. Read the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for a working example. If all you are trying to do is provide animation, then use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. The tutorial also has a section on animation. You usage of static variables and methods indicates incorrect design.

Comment: Class names should not have an "_" in the names. Learn by example and follow the naming conventions used in the Java API.

Comment: @camickr I did what you said but the problem didn't fix but I saw something new. when that black line appears, if you get the dimension using panel.getBounds()  or frame.getBounds() in the button's action listener you realize that there is no difference so I guess that the problem is not with panel.updateUI() method. so my guess is: as panels and frames size can only be an integer, that little change made in the dimension is not counted as one pixel for java. so it's not going to update the panel until the size is not something meaningful for it.

Comment: Swing on Windows has a problem when Windows monitor scaling > 100%.  Your display probably cannot display fractional pixels unless a "pixel" represents multi[ple monitor pixels.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks, not just this but also another problem solved. I changed the scale from 125% to 100% and this problem solved also frame.setMinimumSize() wasn't working now it works fine but even in settings the recommended scale is 125% how can I make it work on the scale of 125?

Comment: also in scaling 100% it is not as smooth as it was at 125% and it became so laggy.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc also tried to set the background color for my frame's rootPane and contentPane but the black line is still black.

Comment: Oracle has a useful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) that will help you build a correct Swing application.  Skip the Netbeans section.  Focus on creating a working Swing application and ignore visual artifacts like thin black lines.  Your code has way too many static fields and methods.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for answering and the tutorial. may I know you said this "Your code has way too many static fields and methods." as an advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: Your code has way too many static fields and methods is a disadvantage.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'm still working on this project and I was reading the tutorial you linked and I realized that even [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/layout-CustomLayoutDemoProject.zip) has this problem.I tried to set the layout of my frame and rootpane and everything under it to null but I can't set a custom size for my rootpane yet.

Answer (score 1):

I hadn't given this much thought since you said in your question,

> I don't want to use the pack() method or any prebuilt layout manager.

This comment immediately disqualified your question in my mind.  There was no way I could answer this question with this restriction.

Here's the simplest Swing FPS Test Example GUI I could come up with.

[image: FPS Test Example]

I use the `pack` method.  I use Swing layout managers.  If this is a problem, keep struggling on your own.

As I said in my comment, Oracle has a tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), that will take you through the steps of creating a Swing GUI.  Skip the Netbeans section.

The first thing I did was call the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method to start the Swing application.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The next thing I did was construct a `JFrame`.  The `JFrame` methods must be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for most of my Swing applications.

I constructed a button `JPanel` and a drawing `JPanel`.  The button `JPanel` holds the Start `JButton`.  The drawing `JPanel` draws the frames per second rate.

I used a Swing `Timer` to capture the current time and frame count.  You can adjust the speed of the `Timer` by adjusting the `int` value in the `Timer` constructor.  I don't recommend a value lower than 5.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class FPSTestExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new FPSTestExample());
    }
    
    private long startTime, endTime, countInterval;
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public FPSTestExample() {
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FPS Test Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Start");
        panel.add(button);
        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private Timer timer;
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (timer == null) {
                    FPSTestExample.this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timer = new Timer(15, new FPSListener());
                    timer.start();
                } 
            }
        });
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            if (FPSTestExample.this.endTime > 0L) {
                long elapsedTime = FPSTestExample.this.endTime - 
                        FPSTestExample.this.startTime;
                int fps = (int) (FPSTestExample.this.countInterval * 1000L / 
                        elapsedTime);
                String fpsString = "FPS: " + fps;
                
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(48f));
                FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
                Rectangle2D r2d = fm.getStringBounds(fpsString, g2d);
                
                int width = (int) Math.round(r2d.getWidth());
                int height = (int) Math.round(r2d.getHeight());
                int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - height + fm.getAscent()) / 2;
                
                g2d.drawString(fpsString, x, y);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class FPSListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            FPSTestExample.this.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FPSTestExample.this.countInterval++;
            FPSTestExample.this.drawingPanel.repaint();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: As you said "Swing on Windows has a problem when Windows monitor scaling>100%" you mean I should Ignore this issue and stick with principles of swing applications cause there is no way to fix this because even this example you wrote has this issue with all layoutManager you and etc you used.this is my [jar](https://ln4.sync.com/dl/14ac5e940#a5s38i9e-6hnzwxzs-xk6kw6rw-mpzashzj) if you couldn't open then the codes(3 java file) are in it. on a scale of 100%, it works fine but some computer's recommended scale is 125% and it should work on them but it doesn't. THAT is my problem.

Comment: my jar file contains some extra info that I needed surely you not gonna need them so remove them also made a lot of changes due to "Your code has way too many static fields and methods is a disadvantage."

Comment: @hamid: I cannot teach you how to develop complex Java software in a Stack Overflow answer.  All I can do, and did, is provide a Swing example.

Comment: Thanks anyway for everything. Do you know any resources, references, or tutorials that I can solve this specific problem? I couldn't find anything useful for in this case in Oracle.